# Is this true that addictions happen due to lack of bonding?

Tags: recreational-drugs

https://www.ted.com/talks/johann_hari_everything_you_think_you_know_about_addiction_is_wrong?language=en

This guy makes some bold claim.

He said that heroin, one of the most addictive drugs out there is not addictive enough.

He said the following. Imagine you go to hospital and the doctor prescribe morphine to you as pain killer. Would people become addicts? No right?

Hmmm....

something is missing here.

Is this true that doctors prescribed legal pain killer based on heroin and people don't become addicts?
Is it true that heroin is not addictive then?

Something is missing?

Some other possibilities

1. Those prescribed morphine become addicts
2. The doctors that prescribe morphine knows how to ensure that users are not addictive
3. Actually the guy is right. morphine is not addictive if used sparingly.

Comment: Have you researched the phrase "morphine addiction"? Seems to be a real thing. Or are you taking "addictive" to mean that a single use reliably causes addiction?

Comment: I am asking specifically about his claim that people are given morphine by doctors and don't become addicts. Is it true? Does that mean morphine is not addictive? I did saw the other questions but that one look at soldiers coming home instead

Comment: Jim, many people *do* become morphine addicts.  It's commonplace.  It may just be that you haven't heard of it before.  (Conversely, many people *don't* become morphine addicts, and many people *don't* become heroin addicts, even if they use those things.)

Comment: yea and what about those people prescribed morphine? Why don't they usually become addicts?

Comment: Well basically every time someone gets perscribed morphine,  addiction is a risk. Doctors being involved dosen't change that.

Comment: yea but most don't become addicts. and here we think that you try drug once you are so death